# vagrant puppet unable to chmod to make executable

Tags: permissions, vagrant, puppet, chmod

I have a vagrant 1.6.3 debian 7.5 with a TYPO3 6.2.9 installation and I'm trying to make a php file executable 
`chmod a+x typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh` but it's not working - not even as root.
When I log out, however, I see that the file has changed permissions outside in my host machine.

I tried adding 
`file {'/home/vagrant/docs/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh': mode => 0777}` to the puppet manifest, but nothing seems to happen.

Can somebody perhaps shed some light on how to make files executable inside the vagrant box?

Answer (score 0):

reson could be the folder you are working with is protected ,

you can try

```
chattr -i /home/vagrant/docs/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh
```

and try to change permissions again